# Skipping code using GoTo (Recursion)

Tags: vb.net, recursion, goto

I have problem skipping some specific part of the code while execution.

```vb
Dim turn as Integer = 1

Function recurs1()

    If turn = 9 Then
        GoTo Endline
    End If

    For i = 0 To 5
        For j = 0 To 5
            If (arr(i, j) <> 10 And arr(i, j) <> 20) Then
                If chance Mod 2 = 1 Then
                    MsgBox("Intialized (" & i & "," & j & ") To 10")    'Line X
                    arr(i, j) = 10
                ElseIf chance Mod 2 = 0 Then
                    MsgBox("Intialized (" & i & "," & j & ") To 20")    'Line Y
                    arr(i, j) = 20
                End If
                turn += 1    'Updating turn
                recurs1()    'Recursion takes place here
            End If
        Next
    Next

Endline:

    Return Nothing

End Function
```

According to my understanding, the code should stop assigning values to the array after value of turn hits 9 and should return flow to the calling function/sub. However, it continues to assign values and Line X or Line Y are printed depending on the value of turn.

If allowed, the value of turn increments up to 37.

I'd surely appreciate some help with this problem from someone with a deeper understanding of the code than me.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Why do you use SQL comment syntax?

Comment: Err, just to make it more obvious that it's a comment. I placed it here only, though. Not in the parent code.

Comment: I hate `Go To`, and NO your code won't stop at `turn = 9`. it will stop only if turn = 9 when you call the function `recurs1()`

Comment: @Jackdaw You should do yourself a favor and set [Option Strict](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) **On**. Seriously. `Function recurs1() As Surprise`

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå Thanks for the heads up, I'll do it.

Comment: Just FYI, you really shouldn't be using `MsgBox`, it's only there for backward compatibility with [tag:VB6]. Use `MessageBox.Show` instead. Oh, and [velociraptors](http://xkcd.com/292/) and whatnot...

Comment: Yeah. I just found out how hated the poor GoTos are. I'll be looking for them as a last resort from now on and thanks for the heads up on the Messagebox.show(). I was following some outdated tutorial, maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have placed the recursive call inside two for loops. The function will be called recursively until turn = 9, but when it returns it's still in the loop where it will be increased anyway without further checks.
Probably it would work better if you checked the value of turn just before calling the recursive function (this way you get rid of GoTo, also).

Answer (score 0):

Why not just put Return Nothing where you have Goto Endline? Return stops function execution, to the best of my knowledge. That would get rid of the dreaded Goto command (it can cause messy code and inscrutable bugs).

Comment: I figured it isn't preferred to use GoTos to break out of things unless there is no other option. Got rid of it, thanks.